# turtle module excludes the attribute after being imported on the IDLE console

Tags: python-2.7, attributes, turtle-graphics

I have python 2.7 installed on my laptop, i installed the turtle module, but when i import, the attribute/methods do not come with it. it gives me error Attribute error: module object has no attribute position

Comment: Please give more details: how did you install it, and what did you try, what error did you get. See [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i installed it using easy_install on the command line, and when i call a method, say turtle.up(), it tells me the module has no attribute "up"